# Python while loop to search for highest value in file

Tags: python, loops, max

I'm writing a loop to search through an excel file. The point is to check for the highest value in a readline. Here's my code so far

```
def maxwages():
   leave = false
   max = 0
   city = '' #city for later printing
   fo = open(path,'r') #open file
   while leave == false: 
      line = fo.readline() #read file
      newline = line.split(',')
      check = newline[len(newline)-1] #the value is the last element in the line
      if check > max: #if the checked value is higher than previous max
        max = newline[len(newline)-1] #assign new max value with checked value
        city = newline[2] #city name
        print max, city #seeing what's going on
      if fo is None:
        leave = true
   print city,'Has the highest wages at',max,'dollars'
      fo.close
```

My current output is

```
"TotalWages"
"City"
1089095041
"WESTWOOD"
325436960
"WOODCLIFF LAKE"
401312434
"WHITEHOUSE STATION"
528315021
"WOODBRIDGE"
896273759
"WYCKOFF"
924776075
"BRONX"
97578251
"BRONX"
98754584
"AVON"
9999157
"BUZZARDS BAY"
```

I'm not sure why the value of max is going down. The file I have to read is 42000 lines of data and I can't wrap my head around getting the correct max. Sorry if there's any vague points, this is my first question and post on the site.

[my data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/106At2VWgwkdbuuqaOjeHDCQhh-dC1-3uSmR_0NoBzmE/edit#gid=1377628668)

*another edit* added my data I'm searching, responses have been really helpful thus far

Comment: what would help is a sample of your input...

Comment: You need to convert from strings to numbers: `check = int(newline[-1])`

Comment: I'll try adding a line here, I'll have to see how it formats. *edit* it looks terrible I'm not sure if it's helpful

`7675 STANDARD WESTWOOD NJ PRIMARY 40.98 -74.03 NA-US-NJ-WESTWOOD FALSE 13245 24083 1089095041`

Comment: So I scrapped the trying to post in a comment, and added a google sheet link to my data, not sure if that is helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this using a different approach.

```
with open(path, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    # Next line will create a list of tuples. Each tuple will be (value, city), assuming value is at position -1 of your line and city at position 2
    values_cities = [(int(line.split(',')[-1]), line.split(',')[2]) for line in lines]

    max_pair = max(values_cities) # It will find the max of every tuple (the first element, which is the value)
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, I am still learning python and didn't know I could do this, thanks for the advice!